# Numpy- difference between calling a "array create function" and "array modification function"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Why do we use np as prefix for creating an array by using function from numpy library and don't use it while calling other than "creating function ".

```
import numpy as np
```

Eg: 1.Creating function

```
arr=np.zeros(2)
```

This one creates an array of 2 by 2 with all elements zero

2.Other than creating function----->

```
arr.reshape(1,4)
```

This one modifies created array `arr`

Now you can see np is used as prefix for first one and not for the second one. Since they are all from numpy library why dont we use it for reshape kind of function

Comment: If you're creating something new, you don't have an existing instance to operate on, so you call a regular function. But if you're modifying an existing instance, you call a method.

Comment: This is basic OOP. It's just like when you use `list()` to create a new list, but `somelist.append()` to modify a list.

Comment: You can use [`np.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) as well.

Comment: @Barmar "...you *can* call a method..." it is actually a design choice, heavily influenced by the OOP paradigm.

Comment: @Michael Szczesny   could you show me one example passing an array object and change its shape with np

Comment: @NaveenKumar - There are multiple examples in the referenced documentation.

Comment: That `arr.reshape(...)` also makes a new array. It does mot change `arr`.

Comment: @Michael Szczesny So when we pass objects inside round brackets () of a function we should mention the module or library. But if we are calling function with object from outside we dont need to mention module or library because the instance itself tells the detail about class and module?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny While using array() function which is used to convert objects like list, tuple to convert to array, why can't we use List object outside array function and call it.Eg.  [1,2,3].array() throws error, but np.array([1,2,3]) don't throw error

Comment: A `list` does not have a `array` method.  The `numpy` module has a `array` function`.  You have skipped too much of your Intro to Python book.

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah I know this. I am just asking there are two ways of calling a method. why one way(outside function) of calling method doesn't work when they are from different class. The same process is going to be done. But why its blocked in one way if its from different class. Any specific reason behind this

Comment: No there aren't two ways of calling a method.  The `np.reshape` is a defined `numpy` function, not just "another way of calling" the method.

Comment: There's no substitute for reading the docs.  All numpy functions and methods have their API page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read some `python` and `numpy` basics.  For `numpy` a good start is

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html

With `import numpy as np`, you have installed a `namespace` called `np`.  You reference items in that namespace with the `np` prefix

```
arr=np.zeros(2)
```

`zeros` is a `function` in the namespace.  It takes an argument (possibly more - see the docs), here `2` and returns an `numpy.ndarray` object ('an array').  This expression assigns it to the `arr` variable.

```
b = arr.reshape(1,4)
```

`arr` has attributes and methods.  `methods` are like functions, but they are "attatched" to a specific object, not to the `np` namespace.  Here `reshape` is the method, and we pass 2 numbers to it.  It returns another array.  In the bigger picture it's important to know that this `b` array is a `view`, though that's not the current focus.

```
b = np.reshape(a, (1,4))
```

`numpy` often, but not always, provides a `function` version of `methods`.  This isn't true for most python modules.

In an interactive `ipython` session we can test code:

```
In [32]: arr = np.zeros(4)
In [33]: arr
Out[33]: array([0., 0., 0., 0.])

In [34]: b =  arr.reshape(4,1)    
In [35]: b
Out[35]: 
array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]])
    
In [37]: c = np.reshape(arr, (1,4))    
In [38]: c
Out[38]: array([[0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Each of the arrays has a `shape` attribute:

```
In [40]: arr.shape
Out[40]: (4,)    
In [41]: b.shape
Out[41]: (4, 1)    
In [42]: c.shape
Out[42]: (1, 4)
```

None of these modify `arr`.  There are actions that do modify arrays, for example

```
In [44]: arr[1:3] = [1,2]
In [45]: arr
Out[45]: array([0., 1., 2., 0.])
```

While it is possible to write `functions` and `methods` that modify objects, such as arrays, most `numpy` ones don't.

A common method that does work in-place is the list append:

```
In [46]: alist = [1,2]
In [47]: alist.append([3,4])
In [48]: alist
Out[48]: [1, 2, [3, 4]]
```

Off the top of my head, `sort` is the only method that works in-place with arrays:

```
In [49]: arr.sort()
In [50]: arr
Out[50]: array([0., 0., 1., 2.])
```

### edit

Normally functions are defined as:

```
 def foo(args):
     ....
     return ...
```

And classes

```
 class Foo():
     def __init__ ...
     def foo(self, args):
         ....
```

and used with a `foo(1,2)` or `f = Foo(); f.foo(....)`.  Here the `foo` function is entirely separate from the `Foo.foo` method.

`numpy` has a lot of compiled code.  `np.array(...)` creates a `numpy.ndarray` object.  That object has many methods.  As with `reshape`, it has explicitly defined `function` equivalents.  Those functions usually convert the inputs to arrays (as needed), and then call the respective method.  None of that is implicit to `python`.

With my example, it is possible to do something like `Foo.foo(f, args)`, that is referencing the method with the class name, and passing the `f` object as `self`.  But that's not what `numpy` is doing.

Each class has a defined set of methods.  `list` has things like `append`, `extend`, `index`.  The names may be similar in other classes, but the action is unique (unless class inheritance comes into play).

This isn't calling the `np.array` function on `alist`:

```
In [58]: alist.array()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [58], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 alist.array()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'array'
```

It is asking the list object to perform is `array` method - which it does not have.

Similarly if I try to use a list method on an array:

```
In [59]: arr.append(3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [59], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 arr.append(3)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I hesitate to use `append` in this illustration because there is `np.append` function, which I have to repeatedly stress is not a list append clone.  It is poorly named, and creates all kinds of confusion.

### USE THE DOCS

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy.ndarray.shape

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.html

This `numpy` page talks, generically, about `routines`, some of which are used to create arrays, others are described as manipulating.  In this list, a name like `ndarray.flat` means it's a array method, as opposed to a module function.

Comment: `numpy` has a lot of compiled code. `np.array(...)` creates a `numpy.ndarray` object. That object has many methods. As with `reshape`, it has explicitly defined function equivalents. Those functions usually convert the inputs to arrays (as needed), and then call the respective method. None of that is implicit to `python`- **Could you elaborate this. What you are trying to tell from this statement. Sorry to bother you. Already you have given me a long answer**

Comment: So                                                                                                                                          
       ` import numpy as np`
        `l=np.arange(1,11,2)`
        `l.sin()`                                                                                                                                                                          This one shows error because `l` nd.array object has no method `sin()` in it.

Comment: `import numpy as np`
`l=np.arange(1,11,2)`
`np.sin(l)`
This doesn't show error because numpy module has function `sin()` which takes in nd.array object and perform sine function on it? Am I right

Comment: `np.sin` is one of a large collection of `ufunc` functions, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html.  These are not array methods.

Comment: `np.reshape([1,2,3]. 3.1)` effectively does `np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(3,1)`.  The list argument is turned into an array, and that array's method is called.

Comment: `np.reshape([1,2,3]. 3.1)` This throws error. Did you mean `np.reshape([1,2,3],(3,1))`. By the way I understood your explanation. We can access methods from outside only if that object has the method we are trying to access